# Нужна ли запятая в таких выражениях?

Tags: пунктуация

Всем добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложениях типа "У неё было имя, как у Ивановой" (имеется в виду, её звали так же, как Иванову), "У него было отчество, как у моего отца".

Answer (score 1):

Для **смысловой центр** высказывания сосредоточен во второй части предложения, поэтому я бы написал так:

> *У неё было имя как у Ивановой// У него было отчество как у моего отца*

Имя было "ивановское", отчество было "моеотцовское"
В НКРЯ, однако, как правило, ставятся запятые в таких случаях:

---

Одна фамилия, **как у мальчика из параллельного класса.** [Карина Шаинян. Локатор (2007)]

— Чем больше мы будем с ними панькаться, — сказал прокурор с фамилией, **как у знаменитого машиниста** — Перебийнос, точнее говоря, Перебийніс, — тем они больше будут нам с вами садиться на голову. [Михаил Блехман. Римские цифры // «Ковчег», 2012]